# Bedeutung von Genitiv + Adjektiv + werden

Tags: meaning, grammatical-case, genitive

Aus *Das Parfum* von Patrick Süskind:

> Grenouille wirkte damit [d. h. mit einem neuen selbstgemachten Duft] – auch wenn er unrasiert, finsterer Miene und bemantelt auftrat – wie ein armer blasser Bub, in einem abgewetzten Jäckchen, dem geholfen werden mußte. Die Marktweiber, **wenn sie seiner anrüchig wurden**, steckten ihm Nüsse und trockne Birnen zu, weil er so hungrig und hilflos aussah, wie sie fanden.

Was bedeutet der Ausdruck in fetter Schrift? Ich gehe davon aus, dass *seiner* ein Pronomen im Genitiv und kein Possessivpronomen ist. Aber in beiden Fällen erkenne ich die Kombination mit *werden* nicht. Ich nehme auch an, dass die Sache vom Adjektiv *anrüchig* nicht abhängt, aber da kann ich natürlich irren.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich um kreativen Sprachgebrauch. *Anrüchig* bedeutet eigentlich *berüchtigt, verrufen* und steht ohne Objekt. Hier wird *anrüchig* aber auf *Geruch, riechen* bezogen und analog zu einigen Adjektiven des Wahrnehmens wie *gewahr, ansichtig (werden)* mit einem Genitiv verbunden, der das Wahrgenommene bezeichnet. Also

> wenn sie seiner anrüchig wurden
> ~ wenn sie ihn rochen, wie er sich näherte

wie

> wenn sie seiner ansichtig wurden
> ~ wenn sie ihn (kommen) sahen

*Werden* trägt wie bei *ansichtig, gewahr werden* nur die Bedeutung der Veränderung, des Zustandswechsels (*nicht gerochen, nicht gesehen* – *gerochen, gesehen*) bei.

Answer (score 2):

Man bedenke, dass es im Buch (und auch in diesem Satz) um Gerüche und ihre Wahrnehmung geht.

Ein gängiger Ausdruck ist

> jemandes ansichtig werden

der etwas altmodisch ist, ebenfalls den Genitiv erfordert und ganz einfach heißt, dass man jemanden sieht.

Süskind hat diese Wendung vom Sehsinn in den Riechsinn gewandelt und sich somit für die Verwendung in einem Roman, in dem es um Gerüche geht, zurechtgedengelt. Hier bedeutet der Satz ganz einfach

> ... wenn sie seinen Geruch wahrnahmen ...

*Anrüchig* bedeutet normalerweise etwas vollkommen anderes, nämlich "von zweifelhaftem Ruf" oder "anstößig".

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, "seiner anrüchig werden" ist veraltet. Aus dem Kontext nehme ich an, daß es "ihn bemerken" oder "ihn riechen" bedeutet.

Ich habe keine Erklärung gefunden, aber gehe davon aus, daß es den Genitiv verlangt, vergleichbar mit "seiner habhaft werden".